# Label Value Not Changing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, uistoryboardsegue

I'm coding a program in Objective C that uses two different views to input data. One view merely displays the view (PSACurrentGame) and the other inputs the data (PSAEnterScores). I'm using a "prepareforsegue" method to pass data from PSAEnterScores to PSACurrentGame. The problem is the label isn't changing. Any idea why?

PSACurrentGame.m :

```
#import "PSACurrentGame.h"
#import "PSAGlobal.h"

@interface PSACurrentGame ()



@end

@implementation PSACurrentGame

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view
    PSAGlobal *global = [PSAGlobal getInstance];

    self.player1.text = global.player1Name;
    self.player2.text = global.player2Name;
    self.player3.text = global.player3Name;
    self.player4.text = global.player4Name;
    self.player5.text = global.player5Name;
    self.player6.text = global.player6Name;

    if ([self.player3.text isEqual: @""]) {
        self.player3.hidden = YES;
        self.R1P3Phase.hidden = YES;
        self.R1P3Score.hidden=YES;
        self.R2P3Phase.hidden = YES;
        self.R2P3Score.hidden=YES;
        self.R3P3Phase.hidden = YES;
        self.R3P3Score.hidden=YES;
        self.ToP3Phase.hidden = YES;
        self.ToP3Score.hidden=YES;
    }

    if ([self.player4.text isEqual: @""]) {
        self.player4.hidden = YES;
        self.R1P4Phase.hidden = YES;
        self.R1P4Score.hidden=YES;
        self.R2P4Phase.hidden = YES;
        self.R2P4Score.hidden=YES;
        self.R3P4Phase.hidden = YES;
        self.R3P4Score.hidden=YES;
        self.ToP4Phase.hidden = YES;
        self.ToP4Score.hidden=YES;
    }
    if ([self.player5.text isEqual: @""]) {
        self.player5.hidden = YES;
        self.R1P5Phase.hidden = YES;
        self.R1P5Score.hidden=YES;
        self.R2P5Phase.hidden = YES;
        self.R2P5Score.hidden=YES;
        self.R3P5Phase.hidden = YES;
        self.R3P5Score.hidden=YES;
        self.ToP5Phase.hidden = YES;
        self.ToP5Score.hidden=YES;
    }

    if ([self.player6.text isEqual: @""]) {
        self.player6.hidden = YES;
        self.R1P6Phase.hidden = YES;
        self.R1P6Score.hidden=YES;
        self.R2P6Phase.hidden = YES;
        self.R2P6Score.hidden=YES;
        self.R3P6Phase.hidden = YES;
        self.R3P6Score.hidden=YES;
        self.ToP6Phase.hidden = YES;
        self.ToP6Score.hidden=YES;
    }

    if ([self.player4.text isEqual: @""] && [self.player5.text isEqual:@""] && [self.player6.text isEqual:@""]) {
        self.R1List2.hidden = YES;
        self.R2List2.hidden = YES;
        self.R3List2.hidden = YES;
        self.ToList2.hidden = YES;
    }


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@end
```

PSACurrentGame.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface PSACurrentGame : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *player1;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *player2;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *player3;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *player4;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *player5;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *player6;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *R1P1Score;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *R1P1Phase;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *R2P1Score;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *R2P1Phase;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *R3P1Score;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *R3P1Phase;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *ToP1Score;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *ToP1Phase;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *R1P2Score;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *R1P2Phase;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *R2P2Score;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *R2P2Phase;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *R3P2Score;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *R3P2Phase;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *ToP2Score;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *ToP2Phase;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *R1P3Score;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *R1P3Phase;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *R2P3Score;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *R2P3Phase;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *R3P3Score;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *R3P3Phase;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *ToP3Score;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *ToP3Phase;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *R1P4Score;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *R1P4Phase;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *R2P4Score;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *R2P4Phase;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *R3P4Score;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *R3P4Phase;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *ToP4Score;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *ToP4Phase;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *R1P5Score;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *R1P5Phase;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *R2P5Score;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *R2P5Phase;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *R3P5Score;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *R3P5Phase;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *ToP5Score;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *ToP5Phase;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *R1P6Score;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *R1P6Phase;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *R2P6Score;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *R2P6Phase;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *R3P6Score;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *R3P6Phase;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *ToP6Score;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *ToP6Phase;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *R1List2;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *R2List2;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *R3List2;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *ToList2;

@end
```

PSAEnterScores.m:

```
#import "PSAEnterScores.h"
#import "PSAGlobal.h"
#import "PSACurrentGame.h"

@interface PSAEnterScores ()

@end

@implementation PSAEnterScores

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    PSAGlobal *global = [PSAGlobal getInstance];
    self.player1Name.text = global.player1Name;
    self.player2Name.text = global.player2Name;
    self.player3Name.text = global.player3Name;
    self.player4Name.text = global.player4Name;
    self.player5Name.text = global.player5Name;
    self.player6Name.text = global.player6Name;
    if ([self.player3Name.text isEqualToString:@""] == true) {
        self.player3Name.hidden = true;
        self.player3txt.hidden = true;
    }
    if ([self.player4Name.text isEqualToString:@""] == true) {
        self.player4Name.hidden = true;
        self.player4txt.hidden = true;
    }
    if ([self.player5Name.text isEqualToString:@""] == true) {
        self.player5Name.hidden = true;
        self.player5txt.hidden = true;
    }
    if ([self.player6Name.text isEqualToString:@""] == true) {
        self.player6Name.hidden = true;
        self.player6txt.hidden = true;
    }

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"enterScoresOk"] == true) {
        PSACurrentGame *pass = (PSACurrentGame *)segue.destinationViewController;
        //Moving scores from round two to round three.
        pass.R3P1Score.text = pass.R2P1Score.text;
        pass.R3P1Phase.text = pass.R2P1Phase.text;
        pass.R3P2Score.text = pass.R2P2Score.text;
        pass.R3P2Phase.text = pass.R2P2Phase.text;
        pass.R3P3Score.text = pass.R2P3Score.text;
        pass.R3P3Phase.text = pass.R2P3Phase.text;
        pass.R3P4Score.text = pass.R2P4Score.text;
        pass.R3P4Phase.text = pass.R2P4Phase.text;
        pass.R3P5Score.text = pass.R2P5Score.text;
        pass.R3P5Phase.text = pass.R2P5Phase.text;
        pass.R3P6Score.text = pass.R2P6Score.text;
        pass.R3P6Phase.text = pass.R2P6Phase.text;
        //Moving scores from round 1 to round 2
        pass.R2P1Score.text = pass.R1P1Score.text;
        pass.R2P2Phase.text = pass.R1P1Phase.text;
        pass.R2P2Score.text = pass.R1P2Score.text;
        pass.R2P2Phase.text = pass.R1P2Phase.text;
        pass.R2P3Score.text = pass.R1P3Score.text;
        pass.R2P3Phase.text = pass.R1P3Phase.text;
        pass.R2P4Score.text = pass.R1P4Score.text;
        pass.R2P4Phase.text = pass.R1P4Phase.text;
        pass.R2P5Score.text = pass.R1P5Score.text;
        pass.R2P5Phase.text = pass.R1P5Phase.text;
        pass.R2P6Score.text = pass.R1P6Score.text;
        pass.R2P6Phase.text = pass.R1P6Phase.text;
        //Setting Round 1 Scores and Phase
        pass.R1P1Score.text = self.player1txt.text;
        pass.R1P2Score.text = self.player2txt.text;
        pass.R1P3Score.text = self.player3txt.text;
        pass.R1P4Score.text = self.player4txt.text;
        pass.R1P5Score.text = self.player5txt.text;
        pass.R1P6Score.text = self.player6txt.text;
        pass.R1P1Phase.text = pass.ToP1Phase.text;
        pass.R1P2Phase.text = pass.ToP2Phase.text;
        pass.R1P3Phase.text = pass.ToP3Phase.text;
        pass.R1P4Phase.text = pass.ToP4Phase.text;
        pass.R1P5Phase.text = pass.ToP5Phase.text;
        pass.R1P6Phase.text = pass.ToP6Phase.text;
        //Setting the total's score and phase.
        //Setting Player 1's score and phase.
        pass.ToP1Score.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", ([pass.ToP1Score.text integerValue] + [self.player1txt.text integerValue])];
        if ([pass.ToP1Score.text integerValue] >= 50) {
            pass.ToP1Phase.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", ([pass.ToP1Phase.text integerValue] + 1)];
        }
        //Setting Player 2's score phase.
        pass.ToP2Score.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", ([pass.ToP2Score.text integerValue] + [self.player2txt.text integerValue])];
        if ([pass.ToP2Score.text integerValue] >= 50) {
            pass.ToP2Phase.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", ([pass.ToP2Phase.text integerValue] + 1)];
        }
        //Setting Player 3's Score
        pass.ToP3Score.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", ([pass.ToP3Score.text integerValue] + [self.player1txt.text integerValue])];
        if ([pass.ToP3Score.text integerValue] >= 50) {
            pass.ToP3Phase.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", ([pass.ToP3Phase.text integerValue] + 1)];
        }
        //Setting Player 4's Score
        pass.ToP4Score.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", ([pass.ToP4Score.text integerValue] + [self.player4txt.text integerValue])];
        if ([pass.ToP4Score.text integerValue] >= 50) {
            pass.ToP4Phase.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", ([pass.ToP4Phase.text integerValue] + 1)];
        }
        //Setting Player 5's Score
    pass.ToP5Score.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", ([pass.ToP5Score.text integerValue] + [self.player5txt.text integerValue])];
    if ([pass.ToP5Score.text integerValue] >= 50) {
        pass.ToP5Phase.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", ([pass.ToP5Phase.text integerValue] + 1)];
    }
    //Setting Player 6's Score
    pass.ToP6Score.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", ([pass.ToP6Score.text integerValue] + [self.player6txt.text integerValue])];
    if ([pass.ToP6Score.text integerValue] >= 50) {
        pass.ToP6Phase.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", ([pass.ToP6Phase.text integerValue] + 1)];
    }
NSLog(@"Value of P1ToScore: %@", pass.ToP1Score.text);
    }
}


- (BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
@end
```

PSAEnterScores.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface PSAEnterScores : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *player1txt;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *player2txt;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *player3txt;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *player4txt;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *player5txt;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *player6txt;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *player1Name;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *player2Name;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *player3Name;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *player4Name;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *player5Name;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *player6Name;

@end
```

Log after one time inputing data:

`2013-11-25 19:04:08.810 Phase 10 Scoring Application[34601:11303] Unknown class PSA in Interface Builder file.
2013-11-25 19:08:11.607 Phase 10 Scoring Application[34601:11303] Value of P1ToScore: (null)`

(The Name of the program is Phase 10 Scoring Application)

I have no idea why it says `Unknown class PSA in Interface Builder file.` I have no class named "PSA", it is merely the prefix for my classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

prepareForSegue: is called before `viewDidLoad:` so your `IBOutlet` will be nil. Try setting the incoming value to a `NSString` and then use that string to populate the `UIlabel` on `viewDidLoad:`

For example

In your PSACurrentGame.h:
    // create a property 
    @property(nonatomic,strong)NSString *gameName;

In your PSAEnterScores.m: modify your

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender 
{

 PSACurrentGame *pass = (PSACurrentGame *)segue.destinationViewController;
 pass.gameName=[NSString alloc]initWithString:pass.R2P1Score.text]
}
```

In your PSACurrentGame.m :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// set text to your label
 R3P1Score.text=gameName;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, what should I do to fix the problem of the prepareForSegue being called before viewDidLoad? I'm a little confused.

Comment: Thank you! That worked! Finally, been looking for an answer to this for forever. This is the second question I asked on the subject (my previous one addressed a different aspect of the problem)!